# Regex value of 0.0-5.0

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a regex string that allows values 0.0 - 5.0. I need the one decimal point to be required. The string below gets me there, but it also allows 5.1-5.9. How do I prevent 5.1-5.9 from being entered, and allow 5.0?

```
^[0-5]+(\.[0-9]{1})$
```

Comment: Checking numeric values with regexes is probably not a good idea.  Why are you trying to do it with regexes?  What language are you working with?

Comment: I'm going to say, regardless of what language you use, *don't* do this with regex.  It'd be nice if you clarified what language you *were* using, but this is one of those nice situations where a regex is actually a poor choice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your regex can match 44.9 which is greater than 5.0, Take a look at my answer :)

Comment: I'm using an application that allows you to define an answer to a question using regex. I'm not programming in any language, it's just a text field with regex support. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^([0-4]\.[0-9]|5\.0)$
```

It matches any number from 0 to 4 then dot then any number.
it also matches 5.0

**Note:** Your regex has another problem that you used `+` after `[0-5]` which also matches `55` for example, so you need to remove the `+`. You also need to remove {1}, It won't make any change but it's useless.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the previous answer.

Comment: Just a small detail, but it's generally better to use a non-capturing group when you don't need to reference the group later.